# Friendly url on pagination url?

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo

I have this

http://localhost/index.php?page=1

And I want show this

http://localhost/index.php/page/1

I have now on .htaccess this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

But this not work, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing your script extension an `page` part

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```